# High memory usage on streaming response through NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having an issue with streaming an xlsx file through a node proxy as it is consuming a huge amount of memory. The file is approximately 11MB large but uses up roughly 700MB of memory when the response is received from a Java service. I'm not sure what's causing this as all I'm doing is piping the response directly through as shown below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');

app.all('/api/*', function (req, res) {

    var options = transformRequest(req);
    var method = req.method.toLowerCase();

    request[method](options)
        .on('response', function (response) {
            logger.info('method=' + method,
                'nodeEndpoint=' + req.originalUrl,
                'mappedServiceUrl=' + options.url,
                'responseStatusCode=' + response.statusCode);

            res.writeHead(response.statusCode, response.headers);
            if (response.statusCode > 399) {
                logger.error(method, options.url, response.statusCode);
            }
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            handleError(err, res);
        })
        .pipe(res);
});
```

Is there something with this or is it normal to see such high memory usage for such a small file?